# Javascript code not working in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

If I select 20 records and click on next button and then return to this page using browsers back
button it must hold the display as 20 and 20 records must be displayed.
This JavaScript code works in chrome. But It does not work in Firefox.

In Firefox what happens is display value and records will reset to 5

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var value = $('#display :selected').val();
  var v = parseInt(value);
  var lp = (5 * v) + 1;
  $("tr.top-per").addClass("hidden");
  for (i = 1; i <= (lp + 4); i++) {
    $("tr#row-" + i).removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select" id="display">
  <option value="0" selected>Display: 5</option>
  <option value="1">Display: 10</option>
  <option value="2">Display: 15</option>
  <option value="3">Display: 20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: No there is no error in console. Data is  resetting back to  5 records

Comment: @KaanCetinkaya  The page is directly rendered by the browser.  Is there any way I can make it work in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this I added an event parameter to the function and event.preventDefault();

```
$(window).on('load', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var value = $('#display :selected').val();
  var v = parseInt(value);
  var lp = (5 * v) + 1;
  $("tr.top-per").addClass("hidden");
  for (i = 1; i <= (lp + 4); i++) {
    $("tr#row-" + i).removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

Comment: checked adding the event.preventDefault(); but its not working. Display is resetting back to 5.   when browser back button is clicked it is selecting first value